# ABP and Table Per Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1, abp

So, in my ABP application, I would like to use EF Core's "Table Per Hierarchy" feature. I'll have a base entity called "Order" and then derived entities like "EnvelopeOrder", "CopyJobOrder", etc.

My question is has anyone used TPH with ABP and what issues might I run into? I can't, for example, imagine how ABP will handle editing different order types. Will I have to check the type of order being editing in my controller and direct to a specific edit page? Or what exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use TPH since it is EfCore related. Abp Commercial [Forms module](https://commercial.abp.io/modules/Volo.Forms) is using TPH.

Only issue was related with EfCore and it was about [including sub-collection for derived type returns repeating items](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22016).

Abp does nothing automagically for TPH specifically since it is EfCore related. So, you need to develop as you require manually.

Answer (score 0):

On you EF core mapping

```
   builder.Entity<StepBase>(b =>
    {
        //Configure table & schema name
        b.ConfigureBaseEntityProperties(tableName: "Steps");

        //Properties
        b.Property(p => p.Order).IsRequired(true);
        b.Property(p => p.IsDone).HasDefaultValue(false);
        b.Property(p => p.MinimumRequiredAccessLevel).IsRequired();

        //Derived types
        b.HasMany(p => p.SubSteps).WithOne().HasForeignKey(s => s.StepId);
        b.HasDiscriminator(p => p.StepType)
        .HasValue<ChangePCountStep>(StepType.ChangePCount)
        .HasValue<ExperimentStep>(StepType.Experiment)
    });
```

on the application layer under *yourAppName*ApplicationAutoMapperProfile
you should map them

```
    CreateMap<StepBase, StepBaseDto>().IncludeAllDerived()
                                      .IgnoreFullAuditedObjectProperties();

    CreateMap<ChangePCountStep, ChangePCountStepDto> 
      ().IncludeBase<StepBase, StepBaseDto>();
    CreateMap<ExperimentStep, ExperimentStepDto> 
      ().IncludeBase<StepBase, StepBaseDto>();
```

Abp underlaying uses Microsoft.Json and NewtonSoft for the serialization, microsoft implementation is the default, They do not support inheritance right now so you have to add your derived types to the excluded JsonFormatter so they will use NewtonSoft

```
                Configure<AbpSystemTextJsonSerializerOptions>(options =>
    {
        //This method will force Abp to use newtonsoft as the json parser
        //TODO: Remove this once we update to .NET 7
        //TODO 2: use reflection to add the unsupported types
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve;

        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(List<ProtocolDto>));
        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(StepBaseDto));
        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(ChangePCountStepDto));
        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(ExperimentStepDto));
        options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(TimerStepDto));

      
    });
```

if you are wrapping any of those types inside any class you MUST also add that class to the UnsupportedTypes

ex:

```
public class SomeClassDto
{
  public ChangePCountStepDto ChangePCountStepDto { get; set;}
}
```

you should add

```
options.UnsupportedTypes.AddIfNotContains(typeof(SomeClassDto));
```